# Running Fabric Commands in Flask Blocks Requests

Tags: python, flask, tornado, nonblocking, fabric

I'm currently running a `Flask` server that import commands from a `fabfile.py` and runs them using:

```
with settings(...):
    command()
```

However, when someone is running a command, `fabric` does not respond to other requests going to the `flask` server until the command has finished. How can I make sure this does not happen?

I'm using `tornado` to serve `Flask` with the following settings:

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from flask_ import app
import tornado.options

tornado.options.parse_command_line()

http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(5000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tornado's WSGIContainer is a single-threaded WSGI server and rarely makes sense to use on its own.  Unless you have a specific reason for combining a WSGI app and a Tornado app in the same process, you'll be better off using a dedicated multi-threaded WSGI server like gunicorn or uwsgi.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this and see what happens.